# wireless usb adaptor problems (system hangs)

Tags: wireless, usb, firefox, internet

I am trying to use an **asus usb-ac51 wireless adaptor** to get internet on my desktop pc running Ubuntu 15.10. I installed the driver for linux that was provided with the accompanying CD for the usb device.
It seemed to work as it showed all the available wireless networks and I was also able to connect to mine.

However when I open a browser (Firefox 42.0) and begin to type something in, the computer hangs completely. None of the methods to restart or shut down works and I have to turn off the power switch manually. All seems to be going well until something is typed into the browser.

I think my problem is more serious than other issues I see here, such as lost connections etc. and I hope somebody can tell me what is going on.

Comment: Can you try another browser like Chromium and tell us if you get the same behaviour?

Comment: Are you using the driver `mt7610u`? Check: `lsmod` If so, please see here: https://github.com/likwidoxigen/mt7610u_wifi It says: "Kernel panics after 1-5 mintues of connection ..." I am not sure there is any solution at all.

Comment: It is actually the mt7650u but must be similar to the mt7610u. When installing there was option for kernel 2.4 or 2.6 only but mine is 4.2. The "rebooting" that was suggested in the link does not work either.  I detest the Chrome but I can give it a try as well. Problem is I have to manually force shut down ...

Comment: Same issue with Google Chrome. As soon as the browser is launched, there is a complete hang. Had to manually push the power button to shut down.